# Convertir elementos html con dimension fija en porcentual

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Si por ejemplo yo tengo estos 2 elementos `DIV` con **width** y **height** fijos

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:1440px; height:400px"></div>
<div style="background-color:blue; width:1440px; height:400px"></div>
```

Y los meto adentro de un DIV con dimeniones porcentuales, de esta forma:

```
<div style="border-style: solid;border-color:green; width:97vw; height:50vh">
    <div style="background-color:red; width:1440px; height:400px"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; width:1440px; height:400px"></div>
</div>
```

Los 2 `DIV's` de adentro no deberia adaptarse al **width** y **height** del `DIV` principal?

Lo que quiero lograr básicamente es un efecto adaptable a multiples pantallas sin tener que tocar las dimensiones de los elementos principales, solo metiendolos en `DIV's` con dimensiones porcentuales.

Comment: Supongo que tú ya habrás comprobado lo que pasa, si los 2 divs tienen 1440 px seguirán con esa medida aunque estén dentro de otro div con medidas responsive, Si no les cambias las medidas no conseguirás lo que quieres. ¿Por que no quieres cambiarles las dimensiones?

Comment: @AiubAl-lal hola, el problema es que el caso original tiene cientos de elementos con dimensiones fijas y yo buscaba una forma mas facil de convertir todo eso en bootstrap, metiendolo en un div con dimensiones porcentuales

Comment: A mí no se me ocurre ninguna otra manera, creo que vas a tener que cambiar las dimensiones de todos esos elementos manualmente.